# springroo addon upgrade all

Tags: spring-roo

when I try to run command `addon upgrade all` srpginroo downloads something and then freezes doing nothing. I have waited long time (about half an hour) and nothing happened, then I had to close console, and after that springroo started behaving unstably so I had to reinstall it. Such thing happened on several computers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enter `pgp automatic trust` first